# understanding python self and init

Tags: python

As might be familiar to most of you, this is from Mark Pilgrim's book DIP, chapter 5

```
class FileInfo(UserDict):
    "store file metadata"
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        UserDict.__init__(self)
        self["name"] = filename
```

Well I am new to python, coming from basic C background and having confusion understanding it. Stating what I understand, before what I don't understand.

Statement 0: `FileInfo` is inheriting from class `UserDict`

Statement 1:  `__init__` is *not a constructor*, however after the class instantiates, this is *the first method* that is defined.

Statement2:  `self` is almost like `this`

Now the trouble: 
as per St1 init is defined as the first function.

```
UserDict.__init__(self)
```

Now within the same function `__init__` why is the function being referenced, there is no inherent recursion I guess. Or is it trying to override the `__init__` method of the class `UserDict` which the class `FileInfo` has inherited and put an extra parameter(key value pair) of filename and reference it to the filename being passed to `__init__` method.

I am partly sure, I have answered my question, however as you can sense there is confusion, would be great if someone can explain me how to rule this confusion out with some more advanced use case and detailed example of how generally code is written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, the `__init__` method is not a constructor, it's an initializer called after the object is instantiated.

In the code you've presented, the `__init__` method on the `FileInfo` class is extending the functionality of the `__init__` method of the base class, `UserDict`. By calling the base `__init__` method, it executes any code in the base class's initialization, and then adds its own. Without a call to the base class's `__init__` method, only the code explicitly added to `FileInfo`'s `__init__` method would be called.

The conventional way to do this is by using the `super` method.

```
class FileInfo(UserDict):
    "store file metadata"
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        super(UserDict, self).__init__()
        self["name"] = filename
```

A common use case is returning extra values or adding additional functionality. In Django's class based views, the method `get_context_data` is used to get the data dictionary for rendering templates. So in an extended method, you'd get whatever values are returned from the base method, and then add your own.

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['new_key'] = self.some_custom_method()
        return kwargs
```

This way you do not need to reimplement the functionality of the base method when you want to extend it.

Answer (score 4):

Creating an object in Python is a two-step process:

- `__new__(self, ...)`  # constructor
- `__init__(self, ...)` # initializer

`__new__` has the responsibility of creating the object, and is used primarily when the object is supposed to be immutable.

`__init__` is called after `__new__`, and does any further configuration needed.  Since most objects in Python are mutable, `__new__` is usually skipped.

`self` refers to the object in question.  For example, if you have `d = dict(); d.keys()` then in the `keys` method `self` would refer to `d`, not to `dict`.

When a subclass has a method of the same name as its parent class, Python calls the subclass' method and ignores the parent's; so if the parent's method needs to be called, the subclass method must call it.

Comment: Cases where defining `__new__` in a class is necessary are rare.  I have done so only once, in writing a `Singleton` class decorator.

Comment: Indeed -- which is why I said it's usually skipped.

Answer (score 0):

> __init__ is not a constructor, however after the class instantiates, this is the first method that is defined.

This method is called when an instance is being initialized, after `__new__` (i.e. when you call `ClassName()`). I'm not sure what difference there is as opposed to a constructor.

> Statement2: self is almost like this

Yes but it is not a language construct. The name `self` is just convention. The first parameter passed to an instance method is always a reference to the class instance itself, so writing self there is just to name it (assign it to variable).

> UserDict.__init__(self)

Here you are calling the UserDict's `__init__` method and passing it a reference to the new instance (because you are not calling it with `self.method_name`, it is not passed automatically.  You cannot call an inherited class's constructor without referencing its name, or using `super`).  So what you are doing is initializing your object the same way any UserDict object would be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

"Or is it trying to override the init method of the class UserDict which the class FileInfo has inherited and put an extra parameter(key value pair) of filename and reference it to the filename being passed to init method."

It's exactly that. `UserDict.__init__(self)` calls the superclass init method.

Since you come from C, maybe you're not well experienced with OOP, so you could read this article : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming) to understand the inheritance principle better (and the "superclass" term I used).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `__init__` method for a class that is inheriting from a base class, you generally modify the ancestor class and as a part of customization, you extend the ancestor's init method with proper arguements.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method of FileInfo is overriding the `__init__` method of `UserDict`.

Then `FileInfo.__init__` calls `UserDict.__init__` on the newly created `FileInfo` instance (self). This way all properties and magic available to `UserDict` are now available to that `FileInfo` instance (ie. they are inherited from `UserDict`).

The last line is the reason for overriding `UserDict.__init__` : UserDict does not create the wanted property `self.filename`.

Answer (score 0):

.. the self variable represents the instance of the object itself. In python this is not a hidden parameter as in other languages. You have to declare it explicitly. When you create an instance of the FileInfo class and call its methods, it will be passed automatically,

The `__init__` method is roughly what represents a constructor in Python.